# SASS - Cannot include sprites from inside Directives

Tags: sass, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

I'm using SASS and Foundation 4.

Since Foundation 4's nature is mobile first, I start by mobile styling first. So it's like this:

```
@import "icons/*.png";
@include all-icons-sprites;


// mobile styles
.some-el {
    // some styles
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
   .fb {
       @include icons-sprites(facebook);
   }
}
```

It's not working. If i call the .fb outside the media query directives, it works.

I understand that you cannot extend global styles inside directives, but this is importing and including sprites, which is gonna be needed in mobile and desktop stylings, that's why I import the sprites in the top, and use them accordingly either inside or outside the media query.

So any way I can do this?

Comment: Your code structure looks perfectly valid to me. Could you share your project on GitHub so that we can clone and test it in action and see all the files, errors and stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by just changing it to something like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .fb {
     background-image: inline-sprite($icons-sprites)
     @include icons-sprites(facebook);
  }
}
```